# Can Glassfish 5 run with java 10 or is it only compatible with java 8?

Tags: java, glassfish

getting error when installing Glassfish 5. I have jdk-10.0.2, now I want to know if this is because there is no compatibility between them.

Am running "asadmin start-domain" and then am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.ini
tializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.new
ServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.cre
ateServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.cre
ateServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceL
ocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContai
ner.java:217)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContaine
r.java:255)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:23
1)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:
371)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)

Thanks for you guide in anticipation
```

Comment: Although Glassfish 5 supports EE 8, and requires JDK 8 at a minimum, it does not support Java 10. Oracle documentation on compatibility between Glassfish versions and JDK versions is non-existent as far as I can tell. If you want to use JDK 10 you can use Tomcat 9 or Wildfly 14.

Comment: For production use is better to choose Payara Server (compatible with Glassfish 5 but with commercial support), from version 5.192 onwards it adds support to Java 11. https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/release-notes/release-notes-192.html

Answer (score 5):

At the moment GlassFish 5 is not compatible with JDK 9 nor 10. The support for JDK 9 will come with the next update as stated at end of https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/java-ee-8-is-final-and-glassfish-50-is-released

Comment: When Glassfish 5.0.1 comes out, yes. At the moment Glassfish 5 is only compatible with JDK 8.

Comment: @GuillemCastro A beta version of Glassfish 5.0.1 is available for download (http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/), and it definitely does not support Java 9. That's not surprising since there would not be just a minor change in the version number for such a significant enhancement. I can't find any announcement from Oracle this year promising support for any JDK > 8 with Glassfish. Perhaps that will never happen, and Payara will eventually support JDK 9+, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 5):

Glassfish has moved to Eclipse: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/downloads

It is also Eclipse that Oracle "sold" javaEE to.

But it is still not supporting JDK 9+

**Edit:** Glassfish 6.0 is out - but it is still only supporting JDK 8

**Edit:** Glassfish 6.1 is out - and it is now supporting JDK 11

Answer (score 1):

Support for Java 11 is coming with GlassFish 6, [expected to be released in June 2020](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/releases/6.0.0/plan). But this is a release to support JakartaEE only, as it's clearly stated at the previous link to the official Eclipse GlassFish website.

> GlassFish 6.0 will move the Jakarta apis into the jakarta namespace as required by Jakarta EE 9. This will be a breaking change for all applications. GlassFish 6.0.0 will support JDK 11+. Support for JDK 8 is not a goal for GlassFish 6.0.0. [[1](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/releases/6.0.0/plan)]

The [home page](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish) doesn't show any plans to support JDK 11 for running JavaEE 8 applications. If you want to do that, consider migrating to Payara Server. It's derived from GlassFish and [Payara 5.194 enables that](https://blog.payara.fish/jdk-11-support-available-in-payara-platform-194).

Answer (score 0):

i'm **working** with *glassfish 5.1*, Glassfish has moved to Eclipse , 
https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/downloads
**notice**: **you have to install jdk8**

next you have to ceate /usr/lib/systemd/system/glassfish.service,

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/glassfish.service
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/glassfish.service
[Unit]
Description = GlassFish Server v5.0
After = syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User = glassfish
ExecStart = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221-amd64/bin/java -jar /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar start-domain
ExecStop = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221-amd64/bin/java -jar /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar stop-domain
ExecReload = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221-amd64/bin/java -jar /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar restart-domain
Type = forking

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

**then Reload systemd manager,**

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and start glassfish.service

```
systemctl start glassfish.service
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf4u5.png)