# Glassfish on Eclipse: JDK required rather than a JRE while I already have JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am trying to install Glassfish5 on my Eclipse. I have the following details for everything:

My Environment Path Variable: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1`

I have also tried with the `bin` at the end of it.

When I try to install Glassfish it gives me `JDK required rather than JRE`, Please find it in the attached image.[image]

I have tried all the available solutions like this question but nothing works. I am using windows 10. I installed the right `JDK` and not `JRE` from this [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk13-downloads-5672538.html).

Please let me know what can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed the Java 13 support plugin from the Eclipse marketplace?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes, I did.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411138/can-glassfish-5-run-with-java-10-or-is-it-only-compatible-with-java-8

Comment: @VGR That is definitely relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to install Glassfish it gives me JDK required rather than
>   JRE

As far as I know, Glassfish 5 does not work with any JDK version > 8. Or more precisely:

- I can't get Glassfish 5 to work with any JDK > 8
- I can't find any documentation stating that it should work with Java 9 or later.

The lack of any formal documentation from Oracle on the situation is frustrating.

> Please let me know what can I do?

There is a simple workaround for you unless using GlassFish is essential: use [Payara](https://www.payara.fish/software/payara-server/) instead, [since it is based on GlassFish and works with JDK 11 on Eclipse](https://blog.payara.fish/payara-tools-1.0-2019-06-new-and-noteworthy).

Payara version 5.193.1 definitely works with JDK 11 since I am using them together.

Comment: @StephenC They may not now, but they definitely did when Glassfish 5 was released, which was after Java 9 was released. If you can point me to any documentation from Oracle on whether Glassfish 5 is supposed to work with Java 9 (or not ) I'd be grateful.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you for the answer, it worked.I installed java 8 144.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/release-notes.pdf, the required Java version is "Oracle JDK 8 Update 144 or later."

The "or later" should be parsed as referring to "Update 144" rather than the Java major version.

So, your options would be:

- If you want to use Glassfish 5.0 or 5.1, use Oracle Java 8 at update 144 or later.  (It probably does have to be a JDK rather than a JRE, but OpenJDK would most likely work.)
- Switch to [Payara](https://www.payara.fish/software/payara-server/) which seems to be where the development effort for the Glassfish code line seems to be focused.

---

Why doesn't Glassfish work on Java 9 and later?

Well it is most likely due to Java 9 modules, and the infrastructure changes that came with them.  My guess is that the Glassfish installer is looking for the "tools.jar" file that contains the Java development tool chain in a JDK in Java 8 and earlier.  Java 9 and later do it differently.