# An internal error occurred during: "Starting GlassFish 5 [domain1]". Can't find bundle for base name sun.util.logging.resources.logging, locale en_DE

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-5

I am using eclipse IDE, and Glassfish5. OS is MAC. Java version is 13.0.1.
I have just started with an EJB tutorial, and found that I need Glassfish. I downloaded and added to my server. Now when I am starting it, following error occurs-

> An internal error occurred during: "Starting GlassFish 5 (2) [domain1]".
>   Can't find bundle for base name sun.util.logging.resources.logging, locale en_DE

I got following on console-

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/kum/Downloads/glassfish5 2/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/Users/kum/Downloads/glassfish5 2/glassfish/lib/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Attaching my screenshot of the error-[image: My error]

I have tried removing and downloading full version of glassfish. But keeps on getting same error.
Somebody help please.

Comment: Does it work with Java 8?

Comment: I never checked. Should it work with it? Let me check with it.

Comment: Yeah, as @howlger said you should try with Java 8. Also see this recent thread for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906790/glassfish-on-eclipse-jdk-required-rather-than-a-jre-while-i-already-have-jdk

Comment: OMG. It worked. I changed it to java 8, and my server started successfully. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, I changed the java version from 13 to 8. The server has started successfully.

I did the following steps-

1. On terminal `brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk`
2. Once above step is completed I typed `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8`
3. Once adoptopenjdk8 is installed, I checked if it is correctly installed. So I did this- `ls -la /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`
   It gave me following lines-

> `drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Nov 27 11:20 .
>   drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Oct 24 14:09 ..
>   drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   96 Nov 27 11:20 adoptopenjdk-8.jdk
>   drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   96 Oct 24 14:09 jdk-13.0.1.jdk`

4. Then I checked my JAVA_HOME by doing this- `echo $JAVA_HOME` This gave me following

> `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`
>   Here, it can be seen that I have jdk-13, which I need to change to jdk 1.8. That is, I have to change my JAVA_HOME.

5. Change JAVA_HOME by `` export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 ``
6. After this, just check the java version by `java -version` I got the following-

> openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

Thats it.
**Dont forget to change the runtime environment in the glassfish server on eclipse.** 
Do it by-Eclipse-preferences-server-Runtime Environments-Select Glassfish-Edit-Change Java Location to your recent `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`