# Glassfish 5 error on start-domain, Error parsing system bundle export statement

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have an issue starting glassfish5. I have searched similar problems on google but found nothing working. From what I have understood it can be my jdk version that is not good but I don't know how to change the jdk used by glassfish. I have jdk 1.8 and jdk 13 installed. Here's the error (full on https://pastebin.com/4Lz91HGG) :

```
Waiting for domain1 to start ..Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: org.osgi.dto; version=1.0, org.osgi.framework; version=1.8, org.osgi.framework.dto; version=1.8, org.osgi.framework.launch; version=1.2, org.osgi.framework.wiring; version=1.2, org.osgi.framework.startlevel; version=1.1, org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle; version=1.1, org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver; version=1.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.service; version=1.1, org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving; version=1.1, org.osgi.service.packageadmin; version=1.2, org.osgi.service.startlevel; version=1.1, org.osgi.service.url; version=1.0, org.osgi.util.tracker; version=1.5.1, , org.glassfish.embeddable;org.glassfish.embeddable.spi;version=3.1.1
ERROR: Error reloading cached bundle, removing it: C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle306
ERROR: Error reloading cached bundle, removing it: C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle307
ERROR: Error reloading cached bundle, removing it: C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle308
ERROR: Error reloading cached bundle, removing it: C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle309
ERROR: Error reloading cached bundle, removing it: C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle310
ERROR: Error reloading cached bundle, removing it: C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle311
ERROR: Unable to delete archive directory - C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle312
ERROR: Unable to delete archive directory - C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle313
ERROR: Unable to delete archive directory - C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle314
ERROR: Unable to delete archive directory - C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle315
ERROR: Unable to delete archive directory - C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle316
ERROR: Unable to delete archive directory - C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle317
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.grizzly.npn-bootstrap [1] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.grizzly.npn-bootstrap [1](R 1.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.grizzly.npn-bootstrap [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.crypto) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.grizzly.npn-bootstrap [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.crypto)])
ERROR: Bundle jaxb-api [3] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve jaxb-api [3](R 3.0): missing requirement [jaxb-api [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation) Unresolved requirements: [[jaxb-api [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation)])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.metro.webservices-api-osgi [4] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.metro.webservices-api-osgi [4](R 4.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.metro.webservices-api-osgi [4](R 4.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.metro.webservices-api-osgi [4](R 4.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [5] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/osgi-resource-locator.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [5](R 5.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [5](R 5.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [5](R 5.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.main.bean-validator [24] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/bean-validator.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.main.bean-validator [24](R 24.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.main.bean-validator [24](R 24.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.script)(version>=0.0.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.main.bean-validator [24](R 24.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.script)(version>=0.0.0))])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [27] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/class-model.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [27](R 27.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [27](R 27.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [27](R 27.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.main.hk2.config-types [46] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/config-types.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.main.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.main.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.bind.annotation) [caused by: Unable to resolve jaxb-api [3](R 3.0): missing requirement [jaxb-api [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation)] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.main.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.bind.annotation)])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [107] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [107].)
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.api [116] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/hk2-api.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [116](R 116.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [116](R 116.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection)(version>=2.5.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.utils [121](R 121.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.utils [121](R 121.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.api [116](R 116.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection)(version>=2.5.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.main.hk2.config [117] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/hk2-config.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.main.hk2.config [117](R 117.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.main.hk2.config [117](R 117.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.main.hk2.config [117](R 117.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management)])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.locator [119] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/hk2-locator.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.locator [119](R 119.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.locator [119](R 119.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.api)(version>=2.5.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [116](R 116.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [116](R 116.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection)(version>=2.5.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.utils [121](R 121.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.utils [121](R 121.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.locator [119](R 119.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.api)(version>=2.5.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.utils [121] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/hk2-utils.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.utils [121](R 121.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.utils [121](R 121.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.utils [121](R 121.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [232] Error starting file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/osgi-adapter.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [232](R 232.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [232](R 232.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [232](R 232.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.felix.framework.ext.ClassPathExtenderFactory$DefaultClassLoaderExtender (file:/C:/glassfish5/glassfish/osgi/felix/bin/felix.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.felix.framework.ext.ClassPathExtenderFactory$DefaultClassLoaderExtender
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:876)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:215)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:261)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
        ....

Command start-domain failed.
```

If you have any idea of what can I do please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: [1] I think you have diagnosed your problem correctly; Glassfish 5 requires JDK 8, and more recent JDK versions will not work. [2] Since you have multiple JDKs installed, see [How do I specify the JDK for a GlassFish domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411138/can-glassfish-5-run-with-java-10-or-is-it-only-compatible-with-java-8) to ensure that Glassfish uses your JDK 8 installation.

Comment: That worked for me ! Thanks.