# Java Development Kit (JDK) is required rather than a JRE

Tags: java-ee-8

I'm trying to integrate Glassfish 5 server in Eclipse IDE 2020-06 but i got this issue **Java Development Kit (JDK) is required rather than a JRE**

[this is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYF9V.png)

But openJDK9 is installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Glassfish on Eclipse: JDK required rather than a JRE while I already have JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906790/glassfish-on-eclipse-jdk-required-rather-than-a-jre-while-i-already-have-jdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Glassfish 5 supports EE 8, and requires JDK 8 at a minimum, it does not support Java 10. ...

For production use is better to choose Payara Server (compatible with Glassfish 5 but with commercial support), from version 5.192 onwards it adds support to Java 11.

find more on [Can Glassfish 5 run with java 10 or is it only compatible with java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411138/can-glassfish-5-run-with-java-10-or-is-it-only-compatible-with-java-8)